# Sort slice of maps

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go, slice

I have a slice of 10 maps, how can I sort by one of the values?

```
[{"name":"a","score":100},
{"name":"z","score":150},
{"name":"s","score":120},
{"name":"x","score":110},
{"name":"r","score":10},
{"name":"b","score":1300},
{"name":"b","score":1500},
{"name":"w","score":1002},
{"name":"o","score":140},
{"name":"q","score":101}]
```

I want to sort the slice with the `score` value, in descending order, but I'm at a loss of how.

Comment: What are the types of the maps, `map[string]interface{}`? Or are they structs? The easiest way is [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice), which even comes with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just a simple `sort.Slice`.

```
sort.Slice(information, 
func(i, j int) bool { 
    return information[i].Difference > information[j].Difference 
})
```